# How can i change the 5th and 6th byte from bytes8

Tags: solidity, bytes, bytes32

**Hi Guys** ,
 How can i change the **5th** and **6th byte** from this **bytes8** ***0x3FcB875f"0000"ddC4***,or just arrive at this solution where:
 ***last four*** bytes(of bytes8) are this way  0x********"0000ddC4" and the first four bytes(of bytes8) can have any number but !=0  ?

bytes8 normal=**0x3FcB875f56beddC4** 
// POSSIBLE SOLUTION //
bytes8 conver=**0x3FcB875f0000ddC4**
bytes8 anothe=**0x********0000ddC4**

### Where 1 ore more of * is != 0

bytes8 another example solution=*0x000100100000ddC4* 
bytes8 another example solution=*0x00a10f000000ddC4*

This is what i try:

  `bytes8 txOriginBytes8= 0x3FcB875f56beddC4;`*// original 8bytes **0x3FcB875f56beddC4***

  `bytes2 twoBytes= bytes2(uint16(uint64(txOriginBytes8)));`*// take last two bytes: **0xddC4**



  `bytes4 fourBytes=twoBytes;`*// add to a four bytes array: **0xddC40000**

   `bytes4 shiftTwoBytes=fourBytes >> 16;`// shifting right by two bytes **0x0000ddC4**

 `bytes8 toEithBytes=bytes8(uint64(uint32(shiftTwoBytes)));`// put in a bytes8 array **0x000000000000ddc4**

`return toEithBytes;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the easiest way is to convert it to bytes, make your modifications and convert it back again like so :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

contract Example {

  function changeByte8() public view returns (bytes8) {
    bytes8 value = 0x3FcB875f56beddC4;

    // encodePacked the value to get a bytes array
    bytes memory array = abi.encodePacked(value);

    // Set 5th and 6th bytes to 0
    array[4] = 0x00;
    array[5] = 0x00;

    // Ensure that bytes 1 to 4 are != 0
    array[0] = 0xFF;
    array[1] = 0xFF;
    array[2] = 0xFF;
    array[3] = 0xFF; 

    // convert back to bytes8
    return bytes8(array); // 0xffffffff0000ddc4
  }
}
```

Tell me if you are looking more for an approach based on bit operators and I'll edit my answer.

**EDIT** : Well actually it's just a few lines, so I add it here too. (I wrote it for clarity, you can be more concise by generating the masks with at the moment they are used) :

```
 function changeByte8bits() public view returns (bytes8) {
    bytes8 value = 0x3FcB875f56beddC4;

    // Bit mask to select bytes 1 to 4
    bytes8 mask14 = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;

    // Bit mask to select bytes 5 to 6
    bytes8 mask56 = 0x00000000FFFF0000;

    // Ensure that all bits in bytes 1 to 4 are set
    value = value | mask14;

    // Ensure that all bits in bytes 5 to 6 are unset
    value = value & ~mask56;

    return value; // 0xffffffff0000ddc4
  }
```

Comment: Ohhhhh gooshh !! Thanks You Sooo Much !!! <3 
I spent so much time on that  !!!
My miss was the fact that i didnt now that i can convert my bytes8 to an memory array with abi.encode() ! 
"And Because on  fixed bytes array ,the single byte can be read only, and cannot be set "
However Thanks a Lot ! 
Love your solution so simple and perfect  !

Comment: Just one Thing Do You Know How To Fix This ? I use your first function and have solidity 0.8.0 compiler .
ERROR:
type conversion not allowed from "bytes memory" to "bytes8".
  --> somenewStuf.sol:63:12:
   |
63 |     return bytes8(array);

Comment: Ah yes sorry that conversion is only available at solidity 0.8.5 and above (https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/06/10/solidity-0.8.5-release-announcement/) my bad. Tell me if you cannot use it I can edit my answer.

Comment: No its Fine 0.8.5 solidity  , Nr 1 !

Comment: Alright, I edited the pragma to avoid any confusion. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Perfect ! However for lower version i just used your second function and its work as magic .